# multi-table mysql query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 4 tables

```
Table: Category
    CategoryID (int)
    Name (varchar)
Table: Products
    ProductID (int)
    CategoryID (int)
    Name (varchar)
    Description (text)
Table: Sales
    SalesID (int)
    ProductID (int)
Table: Links
    LinkID (int)
    ProductID (int)
```

Now I need to display data as:

```
CategoryName     Total Products     Total Sales     Total Links
    ABC                5                 12            50
    XYZ               12                 26            10
```

How can I achieve this, may be in single query

Help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SELECT CategoryName, Count(distinct p.ProductId) TotalProducts, Count(distinct s.SalesId) TotalSales, 
        COUNT(distinct l.LinkId) TotalLinks
  FROM Products p JOIN SALES s on p.ProductId = s.ProductId
       JOIN Categories c ON c.CategoryId = p.CategoryId
       JOIN Links l ON p.ProductId = l.LinkId
  GROUP BY CategoryName
```

Comment: This won't return rows if a category doesn't have any sales. Usually you'll want to show each category, especially if it contains products, whether it has sales or not over the given period of time.

Comment: @GolezTrol, you are right - but did not found this requirement in OP,  changing from JOIN to LEFT JOIN help in that case. (Of course Count(..) should be changed for track NULL values)

Comment: I have changed JOIN to LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
       CAT.Name CategoryName,
       (SELECT COUNT(P.ProductsID) FROM Products P WHERE P.CategoryID=CAT.CategoryID) TotalProducts,
       (SELECT COUNT(S.SalesID) FROM Sales S JOIN Products P ON S.ProductID=P.ProductID WHERE P.CategoryID=CAT.CategoryID) TotalSales,
       (SELECT COUNT(L.LinkID) FROM Links L JOIN Products P ON L.ProductID=P.ProductID WHERE P.CategoryID=CAT.CategoryID) TotalLinks
FROM 
       CATEGORY CAT
```

Comment: Don't use count(*). The * will make MySQL retreive more fields than it needs to and might decrease performance dramatically if you got some large fields (like memos) in your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    c.CategoryId,
    c.name as CategoryName,
    count(p.ProductId) as TotalProducts,
    (select count(s.salesid) from sales s where s.ProductId = p.ProductId) as TotalSales,
    (select count(l.linkid) from products l where l.ProductId = p.ProductId) as TotalLinks
from
  Category c
  left join Products p on p.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
group by
  c.CategoryId,
  c.Name
```